# Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;

Tags: arraylist, groovy, boomi

I'm having the following code block which will create an object with is concatenated string of all objects within "basixCertificateNumbers" array.

```
def object= jsonSlurper.parseText '''
{
    "basixCertificateNumbers": [
        {
          "basixCertificateNumber": "012-012"
        },
        {
            "basixCertificateNumber": "045-123"
          }
      ]
}
'''
def concatdObj = jsonSlurper.parseText '''
{
  "basixNumber" : ""
}
'''

def content = object.each{ entry->
    if(entry.value.getClass().name === "java.util.ArrayList"){
        for (basixIndex = 0 ; basixIndex < entry.value.size(); basixIndex++){
            entry.value[basixIndex].each{ nestedEntry->{
                concatdObj.basixNumber = concatdObj.basixNumber + nestedEntry.value + " "
            }}
        }
        concatdObj.basixNumber = concatdObj.basixNumber.substring(0, concatdObj.basixNumber.length() - 1);
    }}
```

I'm currently receiving the following errors:

```
 Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;
   solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list, e.g. {it -> ...}, or force it to be treated as an open block by giving it a label, e.g. L:{...} @ line 41, column 56.
   asixIndex].each{ nestedEntry->{
                                 ^
```

Even though the solution suggested is to put the label on it, I'm not sure where would be the optimal way to put it.

The current solution would be remove the "{" after nestedEntry, which will be something like this:

```
entry.value[basixIndex].each{ nestedEntry->
                concatdObj.basixNumber = concatdObj.basixNumber + nestedEntry.value + " "
            }
```

However, I believe this is not an optimal way of doing things, so if anyone would have a better idea. It would be a great help!

My desire output would be:

```
{
   "basixNumber" : "012-012 045-123"
}
```

Comment: Most likely you want to remove that `{}` pair there and adding whitespace around `->`. If you want to return a closure, then why are you using `each` (which is for side-effects). I am assuming you are confusing/mixing Java λ and Groovy closure syntax.

Comment: Yea. I removed that ```{}``` and it seems to work. I'm trying to find a better way to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Then I'd suggest to rewrite the question to what you are actually after. Especially what result you are expecting and why your code does not produce the result or how it fails.

Comment: Hey @cfrick, just updated my question

Comment: I was experiencing the same error message and removing `{}` as suggested by @cfrick resolved my error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

```
def content = [
    basixNumber: object.basixCertificateNumbers.basixCertificateNumber.join(' ')
]
String jsonOutput = new JsonOutput().toJson(content)
```

You don't need `concatdObj`

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm!